# How do I get CMake to create a dll and its matching lib file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm using CMake to create a shared library via Visual Studio 2010. The solution outputs a dll file, but not a matching lib file. How do I tell CMake to generate the lib file so I can link other projects to the dll?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all check that you have at least one exported symbol in your shared library. Visual Studio does not generate the `.lib` file if dll does not exports symbols.

Next, check your cmake files - probably you have set `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable or `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property of the shared library target. If these variable/property is set then Visual Studio will output `.lib` files into the different directory specified by that variable/property. (There also can be configuration-specific versions like `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_Release`.)

Comment: I wasn't exporting any functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

add this command to your CMakeLists.txt
`set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)`