# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'external\jpeg-9d\Debug\jpeg.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, sdl, sdl-image

I am including SDL and SDL_image as project dependencies via git submodules. SDL_image contains multiple external dependencies itself, including the problematic `jpeg` library. The overall project structure looks like this:

```
│   CMakeLists.txt
├───build
├───src
└───external
    ├───SDL (git submodule)
    └───SDL_image (git submodule)
        │   CMakeLists.txt
        └───external
            ├───jpeg-9d
            ├───libpng-1.6.37
            ├───libwebp-1.0.3
            ├───tiff-4.2.0
            └───zlib-1.2.11
```

I am using the following top level CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(GameTemplate    VERSION 1.0.0
                        LANGUAGES CXX)

# define common SOURCES variable as all files within src
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/*)

# add main executable (entry point + SOURCES)
# in windows, WIN32 property adds /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS compiler flag 
# required for GUI applications
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${SOURCES})

# SDL (shared only)
# NOTE: setting SDL_STATIC to ON has no effect on jpeg output,
# it just prevents building the SDLstatic target unnecessarily
set(SDL_STATIC OFF CACHE BOOL "build SDL static lib" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(external/SDL EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_subdirectory(external/SDL_image EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# includes
target_include_directories(GameTemplate
    PRIVATE external/SDL/include
    PRIVATE external/SDL_image
    PRIVATE src)

# linker
target_link_libraries(GameTemplate
    PRIVATE SDL2main
    PRIVATE SDL2
    PRIVATE SDL2_image)
```

The following build steps are successful on macOS:

```
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

The equivalent MSVC build steps fail with the error below while attempting to build the SDL_image target

```
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ MSBuild.exe .\GameTemplate.sln
...
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPOR
  T:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\colev\workspace\game-template\build\external\SDL_image\Debug\SDL2_image.dll" /INCREMENTAL /ILK:"SDL2_i
  mage.dir\Debug\SDL2_image.ilk" /NOLOGO "external\jpeg-9d\Debug\jpeg.lib" "external\libpng-1.6.37\Debug\libpng16d.lib" ..\SDL\
  Debug\SDL2d.lib "external\zlib-1.2.11\Debug\zlibd.lib" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib o
  leaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /D
  EBUG /PDB:"C:/Users/colev/workspace/game-template/build/external/SDL_image/Debug/SDL2_image.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1
  /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/colev/workspace/game-template/build/external/SDL_image/Debug/SDL2_image.lib" /MACHIN
  E:X64  /machine:x64 /DLL SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_png.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_bmp.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_gif.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_jpg.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_lbm.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_pcx.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_pnm.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_svg.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_tga.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_tif.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_webp.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_WIC.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_xcf.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_xpm.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_xv.obj
  SDL2_image.dir\Debug\IMG_xxx.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'external\jpeg-9d\Debug\jpeg.lib' [C:\Users\me\workspace\game-template\build\ex
ternal\SDL_image\SDL2_image.vcxproj]
```

Sure enough, that file is not there in `build\external\SDL_image\external\jpeg-9d\Debug`, only the `.dll`. The `.lib` is there for all the other SDL_image external deps though...

```
$ ls build\external\SDL_image\external\jpeg-9d\Debug\
-a----          7/2/2021   2:19 PM         513024 jpeg.dll
-a----          7/2/2021   2:19 PM        1232896 jpeg.pdb

$ ls build\external\SDL_image\external\libpng-1.6.37\Debug\
-a----          7/2/2021   2:19 PM         423424 libpng16d.dll
-a----          7/2/2021   2:19 PM          33612 libpng16d.exp
-a----          7/2/2021   2:19 PM          56196 libpng16d.lib
-a----          7/2/2021   2:19 PM        1200128 libpng16d.pdb
```

If I cd into `external\SDL_image\external\jpeg-9d\` and build jpeg by itself it does generate a `.lib` file, but my understanding of windows is that `.lib` can be either a static link libary OR an export library for a corresponding `.dll`. I assume when building `jpeg` by itself I am building the static link library, and the `.lib` that my main build actually needs is the export library.

If this is the case, why doesn't `jpeg` also build the export lib when built with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`? Isn't building a dll kind of useless with no export lib?

EDIT: I just found this answer indicating `.lib` files are not produced if a library does not export any symbols. I think that is unlikely since jpeg is a popular library, but is there a way I can check to be sure?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7615698/1800023

EDIT2: I found [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160) and confirmed that there are no files exported by `jpeg.dll`... How could that be?

EDIT3: Disabling JPG results in building `SDL2_image.dll` but it also exports no symbols (causing link failure in main project build).

Comment: "I found DUMPBIN and confirmed that there are no files exported by jpeg.dll... How could that be?" - It depends what sources for SDL_image you are using and whether its `external/jpeg-9d` subfolder supports building with CMake (instead of autotools, which don't work on Windows).

Comment: `external/jpeg-9d` does contain a CMakeLists.txt which adds the library. I can build it by itself but it still doesn’t export anything

Comment: I did find that disabling JPG results in an SDL2_image.dll with the same problem (no exports).

Comment: Are you sure that you have SDL_image sources which are actually suitable for building under Windows (without MinGW)? Where have you obtained that sources?

Comment: I didn't realize that there were separate sources. I am using https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image

Comment: I don't think that these sources correctly support building on Windows with dllexport. Yes, their header [SDL_image.h](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/blob/main/SDL_image.h) uses `DECLSPEC` macro when declare the functions. But definitions of this macro they take from the header [begin_code.h](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/include/begin_code.h) which is created for SDL, not for SDL_image. From my understanding, two dependent libraries shouldn't share a macro expanded into `dllexport`, otherwise building SDL_image pretend to build SDL too, which is wrong.

Comment: Not sure I follow the pretending to build bit. Why couldn’t it be built solo assuming you have access to SDL lib and includes?

Comment: @Tsyvarev do you mind elaborating on that last part regarding sharing a `dllexport` macro?

Comment: I am not sure whether my understanding is correct, but still... When SDL library is built, then `DECLSPEC` is expected to be expanded into `__declspec(dllexport)`. That way the linker understands that functions marked with given macro are exported by the library itself and should not be searched elsewhere. In case of `SDL_image` the things are similar: `DECLSPEC` should be non-empty when build `SDL_image` library. But `SDL_image.h` **includes** `SDL.h`. So linker would assume that `SDL_image` defines not only functions in `SDL_image.h` but also functions in `SDL.h`, which is not true.